# Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Cllr.Domain.Business.Wort'.
Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

I'm having this bug on my code...i dont want to paste the code here cause it's a lot of code...and i myself cannot say where exactly the fault is.

so if any one here has this bug or can say what might cause this bug...i will be glad to read your line

Comment: Without seeing the code its hard to say.  My guess is that you are confusing the concepts of constants and singletons.

Comment: I think we'll need the code to say where the exact issue is. The error above is most likely caused by a faulty LINQ statement.

Comment: What is Cllr.Domain.Business.Wort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to do some kind of equality comparison, or some operation (like `Contains`) that requires an equality comparison on an object (in your case a `Wort`). The usual solution is to compare the ID of the object instead of the entire object.

```
// instead of
where w == myWort
// use
where w.WortId == myWort.WortId
```